# Is there an inverse of _.groupBy?

Tags: lodash

I am using lodash and have grouped an array of objects on a key that they shared; I then do calculations to these objects in these groups but now I need to ungroup.

Is there any way to do this in lodash?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`_.flatMap()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatMap) to "ungroup", but it won't restore the original order:

```js
const arr = [2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]

const grouped = _.groupBy(arr)

console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped))

const ungrouped = _.flatMap(grouped)

console.log(JSON.stringify(ungrouped))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect thanks - I did not need to preserve the order as I needed to sort the new combined array afterwards anyway.